# Error in R version 4.0.2 not in 3.6.3 (and previous versions). nls fit

Tags: r, nls

I am trying to perform a nls fit on multiple experiments (say exp1 and exp2).

When running the code on R 3.6 (or previous versions) **it works nicely** (for instance here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php **on 3.4.1**).
On R 4.0.2, I get an error:

```
Error in nls(donnees$ally ~ donnees$allx * a[donnees$allexp] + b[donnees$allexp],  :  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

```
valx1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
valx2<-c(2,7,8,9)
allx<-c(valx1,valx2)
valy1<-c(2,3,8,9,10,12)
valy2<-c(3,10,11,12)
ally<-c(valy1,valy2)
exp1<-rep('exp1',length(valx1))
exp2<-rep('exp2',length(valx2))
allexp<-c(exp1,exp2)

df<-data.frame(allx,ally,allexp)
fitexp<-nls(df$ally ~ df$allx*a[df$allexp]+b[df$allexp],start=list(a=c(1,1),b=c(1,1)))
summary(fitexp)
```

Comment: What is `donnees`? (And it is typically best to include the whole error message, instead of just paraphrasing it.)

Comment: When I run a slightly rewritten form of that, `nls(ally ~ allx*a[allexp]+b[allexp], data = df, start=list(a=c(1,1),b=c(1,1)))`, I get `Error: Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model`.

Comment: sorry. Was the wrong code. I get the same error as you on 4.0.2

Comment: This works here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php NOT with 4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R 4.0+ `allexp` is character whereas it would have been factor in earlier versions of R. Convert it to a factor or numeric variable. We convert to a factor below. Also the data frame is normally written as a separate argument and not part of the formula.

```
df2 <- transform(df, allexp = factor(allexp))
nls(ally ~ allx * a[allexp] + b[allexp], df2, 
  start = list(a = c(1, 1),b = c(1, 1)))
```

Also note that `nls` is not needed since the model is linear and `lm` could have been used with the appropriate formula:

```
df3 <- within(df, {
  b1 = +(allexp == "exp1")
  b2 = +(allexp == "exp2")
  a1 = allx * b1
  a2 = allx * b2
})
lm(ally ~ a1 + a2 + b1 + b2 + 0, df3)
```

Comment: Thanks. Life saver !